# Force the focus on TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

The `DropdownButton` currently has this uggly [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22075), when the user types something in `TextField` and then he taps on `DropdownButton`, the `DropdownItem` stays floating on the screen when it the keyboard get dismissed. See the animation bellow:

[image]

I saw a possible solution for this in one other app, where the developer forces the focus in `TextField`, so the keyboard won't collapse so the issue isn't noticeable. This is obviously not an optimal solution, but for me it can work, since I have only one `TextField` and one `DropdownButton` on this screen.

So let's say I have this `TextField`:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Category name',
  ),
)
```

How can I force the focus?

Comment: You may use the FocusNode  class. Read this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Comment: Thanks @Darish, but it doesn't work. The keyboard when I tap to dropdown the keyboard hides and immediately pops out, which doesn't look good. Maybe I'm implementing the FocusNode wrong. :(